# handle uri parameters in Jetty servlet

Tags: java, http, servlets, jetty

I have created this server with Jetty as below.
I also created a servlet that listens to some uri (/"clientId")

now this is working correctly:
http://localhost:8080/clientId

but I want this to work instead:
http://localhost:8080/?clientId=3

how can I make my code handle the **/?clientId=3** part

I need to handle uri with arguments..

What do I need to add/change?

Thanks!!

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler;

public class ProtectingServer
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server server = new org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server(8080);

        ContextHandler context = new ContextHandler();
        context.setContextPath("/clientId");
        context.setResourceBase(".");
        context.setClassLoader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
        server.setHandler(context);

        context.setHandler(new ClientHandler());

        server.start();
        server.join();

        System.out.println();
    }


}
```

ClientHandler

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class ClientHandler extends AbstractHandler {

    @Override
    public void handle(String target,
                       Request baseRequest,
                       HttpServletRequest request,
                       HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException

    {
        response.setContentType("text/html; charset=utf-8");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String url = request.getParameter("url");
        out.println("<h1>" + "HELLO" + "</h1>");


        baseRequest.setHandled(true);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a setup/configuration with `context.setContextPath("/clientId")`

A valid URL for this setup (and considering your `ClientHandler` code) would be ...

`http://localhost:8080/clientId/?url=myurlvalue`